# Showing error while installing phpmyadmin in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

> By default, phpmyadmin will be configured to use a MySQL server through a local Unix socket (this provides the best performance). To connect with a different method, or to a different server entirely, select the appropriate option from the choices here.

[image: error image]

Comment: did you set  plugin for phpmyadmin??

Comment: yes during installation there was a plugin option so i have used that plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prompt is asking you which connection type you'd like to use. MySQL can use a local file-like resource, called a [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) that is used for different processes to communicate with each other. Sockets are restricted to use only locally, so if you wish to use phpMyAdmin to access a remote MySQL instance this won't work. The other choice is a network connection, TCP/IP. TCP/IP can be used to connect to a local MySQL server, and while it isn't technically as fast as a socket connection it still works fine for my uses.

Basically, if you're connecting to a remote host you'll need to select TCP/IP, otherwise either answer is fine but sockets is slightly preferable.

You should note that user account host names come in to play here as well; socket connections authenticate to a host name of 'localhost', so if your user account is user@127.0.0.1 or user@%, then you wouldn't be able to connect. With TCP/IP networking, local connections connect through 127.0.0.1 (usually), which does use the % wildcard character. 'localhost' is NOT part of the '%' wildcard set.